# how to make command prompt run discord bot on startup

Tags: discord, discord.js, command-prompt, startup

I have made my own discrd bot using discord,js and want it to run whenever my computer starts.
i want it to open and perform the following-
`cd C:\Users\manan\OneDrive\Desktop\project\`

`node .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can use the windows startup folder.

1. Click windows key + R.
2. Type `shell:startup` and click enter.
3. Create a new bat file in this folder.
4. Add your commands:

```
cd C:\Users\manan\OneDrive\Desktop\project\
node .
```

Or the scheduled tasks.

1. Click windows key + R.
2. Type `taskschd.msc` and click enter.
3. Go to Actions Panel -> create a basic task.
4. Set a name and click next.
5. Select at startup and click next again.
6. Select the bat file you want to run.
7. You’re done !

Comment: thanks for the help, may i know how to create a bat file. do i just  make a notepad file with the commands inside then put ```.bat ``` at the end

Comment: Just read this article https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-batch-file-windows-10?amp

Comment: i did read it, and did not understand how to. i tried opening it with command prompt but didnt work, is there a way to this with the simple shortcut way. i remember with my old bot i used to do it and it would workk

Comment: nevermind, i  have done it by creating a shortcut in shell:startup then nameing i cmd, going into its properties and entering the program